# Displaying multiple columns / dataset rows per detail section

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to create a report where each page contains four columns. I initialy had them as subreports but I guess they dont need to be.

How do I make it so each entry in a supplied dataset is represented as a column? Say if I had a dataset with 6 rows, the report would span two pages with four columns on the first and two on the second.

In other horizontal reports I had one dataset row represented as a row in the detail section of the report. But now I need four dataset set rows for each detail section, as the detail section contains four columns.

Guess what I really am looking for is a vertical detail section, sort of, while retaining the rest of the report horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a Crosstab - these are the Crystal equivalent of pivot tables in Excel, or matrixes in SSRS.

Comment: Thank you, i did not know about crosstabs in Crystal Report.
But i need a very specific look on my report. But i think i found a solution, im testing it atm.
I create a master dataset wich contains parameters parsed to the 4 sub report columns. These parameters tell the subreports wich datarow in a second dataset they should use. So im using two datasets. Not sure if it will work.